# Finding the "mean" value

Tags: matlab, matrix, mean

I have the following `matlab` function, the finds the maximum for a number of columns in a matrix:

```
function m = maximum(u)
[row col] = size(u);

for i=1:col
    m(i) = max(u(:,i))
end
end
```

I know that the function `mean` is used in matlab to find the mean value, but how can I use it with my function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) and [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) have a vectorized form which is much easier to use:

```
col_max  = max(u,[],1);  % max of matrix along 1st dimension (max of column)
col_mean = mean(u,1);    % mean of matrix along 1st dimension (mean of column)
```

Incidentally, [`std`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html) and a number of other functions have similar automatic vectorization:

```
col_std = std(u,0,1);    % standard deviation, normalized by N-1
                         % , of first dimension (column s.d.)
```

It's generally easier to use Matlab's built-in vectorized versions.  They're less prone to error, and often have better performance for simple operations like this.  However, if you'd rather write this as a loop:

```
function m = column_mean(u)
[row col] = size(u);

for i=1:col
    m(i) = mean(u(:,i));   % <--- replaced max with mean
end
end
```

Comment: @stewman. Thanks for your reply. What I want to do is first, find the `max` for each column. And, then for the `max` values I have, I want to take their `mean` value. Do you know how this can be done? Thanks...

Comment: @Med-SWEng `mean(max(u,[],1))`

Comment: @stewman. This will only take the mean for the first column, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Med-SWEng No. The inner function (`max`) generates a row-vector that contains the maxima of each column.  The outer function (`mean`) operates on that row-vector, returning the mean of the row vector.  The output is the mean of the maxima of each column.  I highly recommend actually trying these functions out.  Generate a 3x5 toy matrix, use `help`, and play with the functions.

Comment: @Med-SWEng I truly recommend to read the first 4 chapters of the getting started guide, its gonna take 30-40min.